# How to run J2ME application directly on the mobile from NetBeans?

Tags: android, netbeans, mobile, java-me, emulation

Can I run J2ME application on mobile directly the way we can run an Android application directly on the mobile from eclipse? I just want to avoid to run it on the emulator. As in the emulator it is giving some error and I can't solve it.

And also which is the best suitable emulator and NetBeans version to develop J2ME application?

**PN: I am new to J2ME as I am Android Developer.**

Comment: Direct Debugging is not possible with J2ME Devices, such thing can be easily possible with android phones.

Comment: are you sure? if yes how can proceed further?

Comment: 100% sure dear, you need to implement Microlog for debugging. check out this link, http://microlog.microsuite.org/

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your project correctly compiles. If it does, you can follow the following steps:

In Netbeans, right click your project and click on 'Build'. Now navigate to the directory where your project is stored and go to the folder called 'dist'. In that, you will find a JAR file with the name of your project. Copy that to your cellphone and execute it.

And you can use the emulator which comes with the [Sun Java Wireless Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Java_Wireless_Toolkit). It's pretty decent.